# How can I display the background image in tailwind css?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm unable to add the background image in the tailwind Css. It's showing an error in the web page.

How can I over come through this problem?

Comment: Please share your code and the error! Please read [ask]!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `bg-[url(image_path)]`,

example one:

```
<div className="bg-[url('./assets/hero.jpg')] h-screen bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat>
<!-- . -->
</div>
```

example two:

```
<div className="bg-[url('https://unsplash.com/photos/w5zd1EdLLB0')] h-screen bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat">
<!-- . -->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks my doubt was clear